# ALB Ingress annotation - Redirect Traffic by action doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to make a simple traffic redirect from *app/mobile.dev.net* to *app.ops.test.com*
Having  AWS ALB managed by k8s ingress controller I decided to reach that goal using **alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.${action-name}** annotation according  [official docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#actions)

Here is final ingress manifest:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: my-ingress-public
      namespace: test-stg-aws
      uid: <uid>
      resourceVersion: 'version'
      generation: 11
      creationTimestamp: 'date'
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-stg-aws
      annotations:
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect-to-app: >-
          {"type": "redirect", "redirectConfig": {"protocol": "HTTPS", "port":
          "443", "statusCode": "HTTP_301", "host": "app.ops.test.com",
          "path": "/" }
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: >-
          <certificate_arn>
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '30'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health-check
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: >-
          access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=test-stg-aws-logs,access_logs.s3.prefix=l<pref>
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-id
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: >-
    <tags>
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds=10
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
        external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: app-test-stg-aws.dev.net
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    status:
      loadBalancer:
        ingress:
          - hostname: >-
              k8s-test-stg-aws.elb.amazonaws.com
    spec:
      defaultBackend:
        service:
          name: my-app
          port:
            name: http-my-app-api
      rules:
        - host: app.dev.net
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: redirect-to-app
                    port:
                      name: use-annotations
        - host: mobile.dev.net
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: redirect-to-app
                    port:
                      name: use-annotations
```

I expect to see 2 new listener rules on AWS ALB **k8s-test-stg-aws.elb.amazonaws.com** with redirect to desired host **app.ops.test.com** specified in the annotation **redirect-to-app**

However after apply I see different rules have been created:

[image]

Have no idea about this behavior yet. Checked ALB logs and got no luck: no records related with those rules (however I have only access logs). Any ideas how to make this redirect using ingress properly ?

Make setting according official docs